# Is there a way to tell which python thread was the last one making any progress?

Tags: python, multithreading

Let's say I have a python process that starts 50 threads most of which depend on each other. All of which eventually hang because some leaf thread got blocked. Given these 50 python threads I can examine them with `py-spy` and see that everything is hanging. Is there a way to tell which thread was the last one making any progress? Like, having the instruction pointer updated or something.

Comment: This sounds a bit like an X/Y problem... Why would you need to know this?

Comment: You may be able to access these details by looking at internals of the thread scheduler.  Since this will be pretty low level, first question is: which OS are you using? The thread implementation in Python varies substantially between platforms.  Also, I would second the comment from @AKX. The question of "what was the last thread before deadlock" often seems like it would help, but in my experience usually does not get one much closer to finding the solution.  Maybe in your situation ...

Comment: The easiest way to solve this would be to have the threads log what they're doing. Then just see which thread was last to log any progress.

Comment: If you're going to be logging to a shared file from multiple threads, don't forget to protect the file with a lock, otherwise you'll have concurrent writers and the resulting log file will have lines that are a jumbled mix.  This will lead to the classic problem in multithreading though: this method of observation will greatly change timing and may make your deadlock problem go away :)